# Wordpress: Editing 2 columns

Tags: wordpress

I would like some advice on the following issue:

What would be the best way to edit a page that has 2x columns via the editor?

Comment: whats your question.please ask your question clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it with the [Custom Field Template](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/).
For the first column you can use the default editor of Wordpress and for the second you can create  a custom field in which the plugin shows a textarea with TinyMCE support.

Posible code for the "custom field template" to show a textarea in a custom field area:

```
[column_2]
type = textarea
rows = 4
cols = 40
tinyMCE = true
htmlEditor = true
mediaButton = true
```

(you have to enter that code in wp-admin panel of the plugin).

To get the data from the custom field in your the template-file you can use the
 `get_post_custom_values` function:

```
//returns an array
$colum_2_content = get_post_custom_values("column_2", $post_id);
echo $colum_2_content [0];
```